# Using NodeJS EventEmitter on Meteor server

Tags: meteor, server, graphql, react-apollo, eventemitter

I’m implementing an app that makes uses of `EventEmitter`. My aim is to use it on both client and server. But strangely, emitting an event on the **server** does not work:

```
Emitter.emit('SomeEvent', {
   user,
   document,
 }
);
```

The above will work on the client, but not on the server.

I’ve tried importing the event like `Emitter = new (require('events').EventEmitter);`
I’ve also tried to import a file with

```
import EventEmitter from 'events';

class ClassEmitter extends EventEmitter {}
const Emitter = new ClassEmitter();

export default Emitter;
```

My aim is to emit such an event after each database query on the server. I am using apollo and graphql.
Any idea on this would be very thankful.

Comment: Can you please specify what "not work on server" exactly means?

Comment: When I call Emitter.emit('event', data) on the server, the event is not émitter. But when I do the exact same thing on the client, it works.

Comment: Can you please add some code where you exactly create the emitter, add the listener and fire the event. I am asking because usually there is no problem with event emitters in Meteor.

Comment: `import EventEmitter from 'events';`
`class ClassEmitter extends EventEmitter {}`
`const Emitter = new ClassEmitter();`
`export default Emitter;`
It's actually defined in the description

Comment: That's the definition but not the code where you listen to it. There needs to be somewhere a method that should be executed when the event is emitted. Please add it to the question (not as comment please).